# How to get the View in TextWatcher method context?

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, listener, textwatcher

I have a handler that is a `TextWatcher` and i dont know how to get the `View` that has changed text.

Here is my handler:

```
TextWatcher handler = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        oldText = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //v.setText("afterTextChanged");
    }
};
```

Note the commented part, that is what i want, to get the `View` from the `EditText` that has triggered the event, to change the text after the text was changed.

How i can reach this `.setText()` method inside the *afterTextChanged* event? (Like onClick event that view is `v`)

Comment: class TW implements TextWatcher { public TW(View v) { ...

Comment: I can not really understand that. But i got the "idea", can you post a answer containing a example class that i can implement containing this `View v`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
public static class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        mEditText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        oldText = mEditText.toString();
    }
    ....
}
```

Add it with:

```
    mFirstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(mFirstEditText));
```

Comment: `TextFormatter` should'nt be `MyTextWatcher`?

Comment: It worked! But i needed to change `TextFormatter` to `MyTextWatcher` to compile it.

Comment: Is this considered "leak"? There's some recommendation about not passing `Context` around, and I think passing `EditText`,... is indirectly passing `Context`, since we can call `getContext()` easily.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa TextWatcher belongs to the UI, so passing context to it is not a leak.

Answer (score 1):

a kotlin version of @Ion Aalbers answer

```
abstract class TextWatcherWithView(val view: TextInputEditText) : TextWatcher
```